# How can I identify table name from query response (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns two tables data. While I am executing stored procedure from the server side script I got tow tables data together as individual rows.

But on response I couldn't figure out which row belongs to which table.
Can anyone help me to solve this

Here is my code

server.js

```
var pool = new ConnectionPool(poolConfig, config);
var sqlGet = "exec dbo.getTableData";
var data = [];

pool.acquire(function (err, tconnection) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
        
    var request = new Request(sqlGet, function(err, result){
        tconnection.release();
        if(err)
            console.log(err);

            res.send(data);
        });
        request.on('row', function(columns) {
            var row = {};
            columns.forEach(function(column) {
                row[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
            });
            data.push(row);
        });
    tconnection.execSql(request);
});
```

My Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getTableData]
AS
      SELECT * FROM table1;
      SELECT * FROM table2;
RETURN
```

On below code I get list of columns returning from stored procedure, on `column` [I got this response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v59pB.png)

```
 request.on('row', function(columns) {
        var row = {};
        columns.forEach(function(column) {
            row[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
        });
        data.push(row);
   });
```

Comment: Can you try with this
request.on('done', function (rowCount, more, rows) { });

Comment: Yes @PrashanthReddyBalemula but I'm using stored procedure on query so I used' 'doneProc' event listener, even though I couldn't get tablename on result

Comment: You will not get table name may be. But you can write in stored procedure select 'TableName' as tablename... . So you will get in select list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @PrashanthReddyBalemula, As from his comment, I solved my problem by returning table name from the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getTableData]
AS
      SELECT *, 'MyTable1' as TableName FROM table1;
      SELECT *,'MyTable2' as TableName FROM table2;
RETURN
```

By this I can get the table's name from the field `TableName`